# Merge nested params via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, merge, nested-attributes, parameters, ransack

I'm using nested params (via ransack nested as q) alongside normal params to build links on a page and am having trouble with getting the two to play nicely when I try and merge the nested params with the other params.

For example if I have:

```
{"freq"=>"weekly", "loan_amount"=>"350000",
"q"=>{"lowEquity_true"=>"1", "s"=>"rate asc"}}
```

and try and build a link to change the param "lowEquity_true" with

```
rates_url(params[:q].merge(:lowEquity_true => '0'))
```

then I end up with the new params below, which looks like its updated q but dropped the rest of the params.

```
{"lowEquity_true"=>"0", "s"=>"rate asc"}
```

If I instead try to merge q & merge into the other params it doesn't update q, and just merges what was in q into the other params instead

```
rates_url(params[:q].merge(:lowEquity_true => '0').merge(params))

{"freq"=>"weekly", "loan_amount"=>"350000", "lowEquity_true"=>"0",
 "q"=>{"lowEquity_true"=>"1", "s"=>"rate asc"},
 "s"=>"rate asc"}
```

I've tried all sorts of various combinations and don't appear to be getting anywhere so am sure that I'm missing something basic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

Let me explain with an example :

```
params = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :q => {:x => 24, :y => 25}}
```

At this point, `params[:q]` is

```
{:x=>24, :y=>25}
```

If I do,

```
params[:q].merge(:x => 99)
```

then my `params[:q]` will become

```
 {:x=>99, :y=>25}
```

and this is what you are supplying as an argument to `rates_url(params[:q].merge(:lowEquity_true => '0'))`

that's why only `{"lowEquity_true"=>"0", "s"=>"rate asc"}` is passed to `rates_url` as parameters.

Now, if you do something like

```
params[:q].merge(:x => 99).merge(params)
```

then `params[:q].merge(:x => 99)` gives you `{:x=>99, :y=>25}` and then it merges `{:x=>99, :y=>25}` into the original params `{:a => 1, :b => 2, :q => {:x => 24, :y => 25}}`
, so this results into

```
 {:x=>99, :y=>25, :a=>1, :b=>2, :q=>{:x=>24, :y=>25}}
```

Now, let me explain you what you should do :-

You params is

```
{"freq"=>"weekly", "loan_amount"=>"350000",
"q"=>{"lowEquity_true"=>"1", "s"=>"rate asc"}}
```

So, you should do :

```
params[:q].merge!(:lowEquity_true => '0')

rates_url(params)
```

That's it

I hope you khow the difference between `merge` and `merge!` :- 
`merge!` is destructive, it will modify the original paramter where as `merge` will not unless you take it in a variable and use it.

Alternatively, if you want to do the same thing stated above in a single line then, just do

```
rates_url(params.merge!(:q => {:lowEquity_true => '0', "s"=>"rate asc"}))
```

OR

```
rates_url(params.merge(:q => params[:q].merge(:lowEquity_true => '0')))
```